# Вызов метода класса в другом методе этого же класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Скажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Нужно вызвать метод класса в другом методе этого же класса:

```
class userControl:
    def delFromArray(arr,count):
        i = 1
        while i <= count:
            del arr[0]
            i=i+1
        return arr

    def getStudentMark(self,login,group):
        with open("files/groups/"+group+".txt") as file:
            group = [row.strip() for row in file]

        objects = group[0].split('|')
        del group[0]
        delFromArray(objects,5)

        resArr = 'empty'
        marks = 'empty'
        i = 0       
        while i < len(group):
            if(group[i].find(login,0,len(group[i])) != -1):
                marks = group[i].split('|')
                break
            i = i + 1
        if(marks != 'empty'):
            delFromArray(marks,5)
            resArr = [objects,marks,getAverangeVal(marks)]
        return resArr
```

При попытке вызвать метод:  `delFromArray(objects,5)`, говорит, что нет такой функции. Как правильно это делается в питоне?

Comment: `self.delFromArray(objects,5)`

Comment: либо вынести функцию `def delFromArray(arr,count)` за пределы класса

Comment: Спасибо, дружище. Ответь полноценно, отмечу как ответ на мой вопрос. Все работает! первый вариант лучше подходит)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delFromArray(arr,count)` - это вызов внешней функции, которая определена вне класса. Чтобы внутри класса вызвать один из методов самого класса нужно добавлять к вызову `self`. Т.е. `self.delFromArray(arr,count)`.
Так как данный метод все-таки определен внутри класса, то его стоит сделать статическим:

```
@staticmethod
def delFromArray(arr,count):
    pass
```

Comment: Учту, спасибо)))

Answer (score -1):

```
def delFromArray(self,arr,count):
```

Comment: Или я дурак или все-таки этого не достаточно. Пробовал, ошибка та же.